# Don't work "db.results_as_hash = true" in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sqlite, sqlite3-ruby

I connect to database and change db.results_as_hash to true

```
db = SQLite3::Database.new 'barbershop.sqlite'
db.results_as_hash = true
```

But it don't display hash, it is simple array.
And don't work

```
<% @results.each do |row| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= row['Name'] %></td>
```

Working code is

```
<% @results.each do |row| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= row[1] %></td>
```

**Error is "no implicit conversion of String into Integer"**

What's wrong?

Ruby 2.1.5p273, SQLite version 3.8.5, MacOS X Yosemite

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code can you post the actual section of code that sets `@results`. e.g. the controller action if this is rails (can't tell because you are using erb but you are also setting the database explicitly)

Comment: I use Sinatra, erb.
@results = db.execute 'SELECT * FROM Users ORDER BY Id' . May be I must install some gem?

Comment: what do you mean by "And don't work"? Is there an error? Are you sure that the column is named "Name" (uppercase?) or could it be "name" (lowercase?). There is no additional dependancy for this feature although it is suggested in the [docs](http://sqlite-ruby.rubyforge.org/sqlite3/faq.html#538670736) that using [`arrayfields`](https://github.com/ahoward/arrayfields) is an option as well.

Comment: Error is "no implicit conversion of String into Integer". Name of column does not influence

Comment: Okay that clearly indicates your assumption of an Array is correct although I still cannot find fault with your code. maybe try using arrayfields and see if that helps.

Comment: Thank you! May be is a bug of sqlite3 or MacOS X?

Comment: Can you attach the code that sets `@results`?

Comment: <table class="table">

 <% @results.each do |row| %>
  <tr>
   <td><%= row[1] %></td>
   <td><%= row[2] %></td>
   <td><%= row[3] %></td>
   <td><%= row[4] %></td>
   <td><%= row[5] %></td>
  </tr>
 <% end %>

</table>

Comment: Nope, the code that *sets* `@results`.  The query, most likely.

Comment: @results = db.execute 'SELECT * FROM Users ORDER BY Id DESC' - ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [repo you posted](https://github.com/dizverst/barbershop).  You're not actually setting that flag.  The code in your question is not the code you're running.  There's no `db` variable, and you `return` on the first line, so the second never runs.

```
def get_db
  return SQLite3::Database.new 'barbershop.sqlite'
  db.results_as_hash = true
end
```

I'm guessing that only compiles because the last line isn't executing.  Try this:

```
def get_db
  db = SQLite3::Database.new 'barbershop.sqlite'
  db.results_as_hash = true
  db
end
```

Comment: nice catch I did not even see a repo posted ou that would have immediately reviewed the source. BTW since this is ruby there is no compilation as this would be interpreted in real time (thus no error because it never interprets the erroneous line)